# My $.ajax call is doing nothing

Tags: jquery

I am executing the following and sending a request to my MVC controller.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Administration/Packages/GetOptions",
        data: { ac: accountID,
                pr: productID,
                pa: packageID
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#PackageID').html(data);
        }
    });
```

When I put a breakpoint in my controller it sometimes gets reached and sometimes does not. I didn't set up any caching that I know of but it seems like maybe the browser is doing caching. It's important the call goes directly to the server. Is there some way I can ensure this happens? If the user has set up caching then I don't want it to be used. I want a fresh call to the server every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `cache: false`

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/Administration/Packages/GetOptions",
    data: { ac: accountID,
            pr: productID,
            pa: packageID
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#PackageID').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that's fixed it !!!!   Geez I wish I could award you twenty points !!!!!   I'll do some more testing and mark as accepted when I'm sure it is okay.